# How to make xargs read input from starting from specific line?

Tags: bash, xargs

For example I use this command to list all containers of name django project
`docker ps -q --filter "status = exited" --filter "name = django_project"`
Problem is that I can't remove the first line of output that looks like
**CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES** and I want to use xargs to do things on my containers.

Googling. Really hard. But I didn't find any elegant looking answer. I can do it using variable and trimming that first line but I want to keep my code as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
docker ps -q --filter "status = exited" --filter "name = django_project" | tail -n +2 | xargs ...
```

to remove the first line of output

Comment: Oh! That's neat! Thank you, sir! :D Unfortunatelly I can't upvote because I lack rep points.